# The oldest person in a birthday table. SQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the oldest person in my Members' birthday table from Vermont and New York. My Members resembles the following:

```
Members
-------
MemberID, Firstname, Lastname, Birthday, Region
```

I formulated the following subquery:

```
SELECT lastname 
FROM members 
WHERE region = 'VT' 
  AND year(birthday) > (SELECT year(birthday) 
                        FROM members 
                        WHERE region = 'NY')
```

SQL query system tells me that it returns more than one row. What am I missing in it and is it logically correct? Again, am I asking how I can find every member in Vermont who is older than all the members from NY.

Comment: What I am saying with the '>' logical operator is if the birthday year of the outer query is greater than the birthday of the inner query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find max birthday of NY members, so that you get only one value. Then use that value to find VT member greater than that max value of NY

You may try this:

```
select lastname 
from members where region = 'VT' and year(birthday) >
(select max(birthday) from members where region = 'NY')
```

The logical operator `>` requires that there should be only 1 value on the right side of the operator.

Comment: Also, you may remove the `year` from `year(birthday)` from your query. You would not need that.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select top 1 * from table where region='vermont' or region ='newyork' order by year(birthday) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
select lastname from members where region = 'VT' and year(birthday) 
>
(select year(birthday) from members where region = 'NY' ORDER BY birthday ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Why will I need ASC (ascending) with a limit of 1?

Comment: @user2948897 ascending would be increasing order and LIMIT 1 would give you a single result, so it gives you birthday that is the highest in table

Answer (score 1):

I don't get most of these answers.  They don't address the NY & VT requirement (other than to reproduce the ambiguous question vs "what I tried").  Also surely the older the person the *smaller* their birthday.

```
SELECT lastname 
FROM members 
WHERE region in('VT' ,'NY') and birthday = 
(SELECT MIN(birthday) 
FROM members where
region in('VT' ,'NY') )
```